# Rename Files but do not explicitly know the file extension

Tags: rename

So I have a csv file that has two columns, OrigFilename|NewFilename and I have a directory with over 1k files. The issue is, my list does not have file extension.  How would I go about renaming the file, to the new filename without explicitly defining a file extension but instead just use the extension that is in the original filename?

This is what I have but it requires the file extension. I'm having an issue of formulating a hash table to get the extension in there.

$Renames = Import-csv "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\pull\rename.csv" $TargetDir = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\pull" $RenHash = @{} $Renames | ForEach-Object { $RenHash[$*.OName]=$*.NName } Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetDir -Recurse -Include $Renames.OName | Rename-Item -NewName {$RenHash[$_.Name]}

Comment: What tools do you have?  Can you write PowerShell, assuming you're on Windows? Any  programming languages you know?

Comment: This is what i have but it forces me to define the file ext.

$Renames = Import-csv "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\pull\rename.csv"
$TargetDir = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\pull"

$RenHash = @{}
$Renames | ForEach-Object { $RenHash[$_.OName]=$_.NName }

Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetDir -Recurse -Include $Renames.OName | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$RenHash[$_.Name]}

Comment: Pardon, I was asking about your abilities as a programmer.  If you know PowerShell, (and are on a Windows computer), we can give an answer in PowerShell. If not, but you know C#, we can answer in C#, etc.

Comment: my bad, windows and PS is great!

Comment: Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.   Note that I changed the header line in your csv from `OrigFilename|NewFilename` to `OrigFilename,NewFilename` so it too is comma-delimited like the rest of your file presumably is.

I didn't test recursing into folders, or files with the same name but different extensions.

```bsh
$Renames = Import-csv ".\fromTo.csv" 

$TargetDir = "files" 

$Renames | ForEach-Object { 
  $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetDir -Recurse -Include ($_.OrigFilename + ".*") 
  $ext = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)
  $newName = $_.NewFilename + $ext;
  Rename-Item  -Path $file -NewName $newName 
}
```

Comment: Thanks...i really need to get on board with all the ps objects. reading what you developed makes so much sense...thanks!!!